# Разбить месяц по дням

Tags: mysql

Имеются таблица с данными за месяц.

```
date       tcy
2012-10-01 5000
2012-11-01 5200
2012-12-01 5600
```

Необходимо вывести эти данные для каждого дня месяца.
Т.е. на выходе должно получится

```
date       tcy
2012-10-01 5000
2012-10-02 5000
2012-10-03 5000
....
2012-10-31 5000
2012-11-01 5200
2012-11-02 5200
2012-11-03 5200
...
2012-11-30 5200
2012-12-01 5600
2012-12-02 5600
2012-12-03 5600
...
2012-12-31 5600
```

Comment: Может удобнее будет это реализовывать на языке программирования?

Comment: Удобнее это да, но вопрос в том что систему очень запутана использует объекты Doctrine2. После генерации средствами php придется переписывать часть системы( чего делать очень не хочется), либо как-то воссоздавать объект доктрины.

Comment: по началу подумал, что вопрос простой, и обойдется все решение с помощью **group by DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d')**, но дело оказалось серьезнее...


Вот нашел кое-что для простого sql:
http://www.sql.ru/forum/775883/spisok-dat-mezhdu-dvumya-zadannymi

а в твоем случае, думаю можно с помощью процедур сделать )

Comment: А создать таблицу с датами (пусть автоматически) с помощью хранимой процедуры, а затем join по месяцу?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно использовать [preg-match](http://preg-match.com/)

Comment: Это ж php. А парень видишь, только мускул указал..